# Caching async requests in Pytest test function

Tags: python, caching, pytest, python-asyncio, httpx

I have implemented a test function in `pytest` which loads data from files, casts it into Python objects and provides a new object for each test.

Each one of these objects contains a request I need to make to the server and the expected responses, the function looks like this:

```py
@pytest.mark.asyncio
@pytest.mark.parametrize('test', TestLoader.load(JSONTest, 'json_tests'))
async def test_json(test: JSONTest, groups: Set[TestGroup], client: httpx.AsyncClient):
    skip_if_not_in_groups(test, groups)

    request = Request(url=test.url, body=test.body.dict())
    response = await client.post(request.url, json=request.body)

    # Assertions down here...
```

Many times I send many requests that contain the same `http` endpoint with the same `body` so the response is the same, but I'm testing for different things in the response.

Because of that I thought of implementing an in-memory cache so that for each test run the same requests won't be implemented twice.

What I've tried to do is create a request object, with its own `__hash__` implementation and use the `@asyncstdlib.lru_cache` on the function, it didn't seem to work.

```py
# Does not work...

@asyncstdlib.lru_cache
async def send_request(request: Request, client: httpx.AsyncClient):
    return await client.post(request.url, json=request.body)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
@pytest.mark.parametrize('test', TestLoader.load(JSONTest, 'json_tests'))
async def test_json(test: JSONTest, groups: Set[TestGroup], client: httpx.AsyncClient):
    skip_if_not_in_groups(test, groups)

    request = Request(url=test.url, body=test.body.dict())
    response = await send_request(request)
```

The client I'm using: `httpx.AsyncClient` also implements `__hash__`, it's coming from a `pytest.fixture` in `conftest.py` and it has a scope of 'session':

```
# conftest.py

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def event_loop(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
async def client() -> httpx.AsyncClient:
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        yield client
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? It throws errors or you don't get what you want? From what you've posted I see that you don't return anything from send_request but just do the post request await client.post(request.url, json=request.body)

Comment: Im sorry its a typo from uploading the code to here, by not working I mean I'm sending 7 requests that are the same and the server gets 7 requests instead of 1, if it was cached the `response` object would be available to use without sending another request to the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let go of the opaque 3rd party cache, and cache yourself.
Since you don't require cleaning-up the cache during a single execution, a plain dictionary will work:

```
_cache = {}


async def send_request(request: Request, client: httpx.AsyncClient):
    if request.url not in _cache:
        _cache[request.url] = await client.post(request.url, json=request.body)
    return _cache[request.url]
```

Comment: works great, thank you!

Comment: But is it not possible that multiple execution flows end up at "await client.post(...)" and thus the benefits of the caching process is somewhat reduced

Comment: this solutoin use the url as cache key. Ultimately it depends on the API being called  if any caching makes sense at all - in general, `post`requests should not be cached, actually, as each post, when talking REST principles, will create a new, distinct, resource on the server. 
Other times it might make sense to use not only the URL, but some of the fields in the request.body as well - one should just pay attention in what they are doing, and not just copy this blindly.